# "Boys will be boys!" Is 'will be' a future simple of 'be' or a present simple of modal auxiliary 'will'?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, future, present-tense

In the proverb:

> Boys will be boys!

is 'will be' one verb or two?

1. the *future simple of 'be'* (one verb)?

   or
2. the *present simple of modal auxiliary 'will'* + the *bare present infinitive of 'be'* (two verbs)?

Comment: future simple of _be_

Comment: I suspect this must be to do with the deontic, epistemic, and dynamic uses of modal auxiliaries, but I cannot come up with an answer

Comment: *will be* is never a "single verb." it's either future will or intentional will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries seem to find the analysis difficult too.  AHD seems to include this usage amongst the auxiliary ones:

> aux 5. Used to indicate intention: I will too if I feel like it.

**AND** among the main verb usages:

> tr. & intr.v. To wish; desire: Do what you will [do]. Sit here if you will.
>   [Behave just like all the other silly boys if you will: *be* a boy / stupid / whatever you will] [Be one of the boys if you will]

Collins classes it solely as an auxiliary usage:

> 1. used as an auxiliary to express customary practice or inevitability: boys will be boys.

I think the future simple 'Boys are still going to be boys in the future' (though allowable) is not usually intended.

Comment: That's interesting, because the last statement is pretty much what the Latin phrase *is* saying. I don't think it's a deliberate act; it's just (to me) statement of fact. Children are children, and will act like children.

Comment: I agree. if I say 'My children will wipe their noses on the curtains', I am not intending the future tense in any way shape or form!

Comment: @Susan 'He _will_ keep on ...' can have the 'he persists in ...' sense (as WS2 implies) as well as the unmarked future. From the internet: 'I need quiet to write this but he will keep on talking to me. I wish he would leave me alone.' This is certainly not a future simple usage....

Comment: The non-future usage is endorsed: **Boys will be boys.**
Prov. Boys are expected to be irresponsible or boisterous. (Also said ironically about men.) _You can't blame David for breaking the window with his baseball. Boys will be boys._ //  _My husband can't resist driving eighty miles an hour in his new sports car. Boys will be boys._

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002  ///

Something that you say which means it is not surprising when boys or men behave in a noisy, rude, or unpleasant way.

Cambridge Idioms Dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters how it is interpreted (I think it can be interpreted either way), it still means basically the same thing.

As a modal verb, it indicates [likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb)*. As a future, it simply *predicts* (also a likelihood).

This term came from a Latin proverb, **sunt pueri pueri, pueri puerilia tractant** "Boys are boys, boys do boyish things" or, perhaps better, "Children are children, children do childish things." In English it was first recorded in [1589](http://www.yourdictionary.com/boys-will-be-boys).

---

*likelihood, ability, permission, obligation, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You have discovered a curious thing:

The tenses of to be are: he is, he was, he will be, he would be etc.
"will be" (the group of the two words) is called simple Future and it is formed with the verb will (a modal verb and an auxiliary verb in Present Tense + be, infinitive).

Ah, now I understand what you really ask. Well, I think there are various answers possible. 
But I would regard it as a Future tense with the connotation: Boys will always be boys, they don't change their childish habits.

Of course, there might be the view, that "will" might mean "Boys simply want to be boys". And one must say, that view is possible. But the difference is so slight that, at least for me, it is of minor importance how you interpret it. Nevertheless, I personally, would tend to the first view.

Comment: And if I say 'The fourth form boys will insist on spitting on the heads of people from the stairwell', am I using the future tense? I think not!